# Why does Close | Off-Topic | Other SE site not list all sites?

Tags: feature-request

Over on stackoverflow, under review, `Close Question | Off-Topic | Belongs on other SE site` only lists a handful of available Stack Exchange web sites to redirect the question to.

I would like to humbly suggest that Computer Science be added to that list. There are quite a few questions posted that are about that and not exactly about programming per se.

Comment: Those are the "auto migration" paths available based on a number of things, previous migration success rate among them. For other sites you have to use a custom moderator flag.

Comment: Also, there's only enough space for 6 sites there (or a list with scrolling).

Comment: Don't forget the [Don't migrate crap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225006/add-a-dont-migrate-crap-migration-path-to-all-sites) rule

Comment: I would like to humbly suggest that Computer Science be added to that list. There are quite a few questions posted that are about that and not exactly about programming per se.

Comment: @rene: I'll try not to :)

Comment: There is a _tiny_ number of questions here that would be suitable for Computer Science and totally unsuitable to stay on Stack Overflow (rule of thumb - if a question fits the scope of the site it was asked on - it shouldn't be migrated)

Comment: Original question didn't make sense, if you think about it.  Ask a parenting question on SO, you shouldn't be migrated, you should be jailed.

Comment: @Will: I see your point. To be fair, I haven't yet seen any questions that were that far off topic :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I saw a question about discrete math a while back. It was very funny (and yet frustrating) when I kept telling him it had nothing to do with programming. People ask *weird* questions here sometimes.

Comment: An idea I had awhile back for a different migration interface: [Better “Flag for migration” interface](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210545/213963) that would effectively allow for 'all the sites' (though still go through the mods as flags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason is that it is proved by experience that SO users *overall* don't actually have a good grasp of what is on topic on other SE sites.

For instance, I've witnessed many times a question closed on SO, and reposted on Programmers.SE at the suggestion of one or more SO users. Every single time, the question was closed on Programmers.SE too.

It is bad enough that moderators on the other sites have sometimes requested their site be removed from the list of options.

Comment: in that case then, Why does Close | Off-Topic | Other SE site list any sites at all?

Answer (score 4):

There have only been 10 migrations to Computer Science from SO over the past 90 days, 1 of which was rejected.  There are 14 other sites that have had more questions successfully migrated to them than Computer Science over the past 90 days.

That's just not enough traffic to warrant being one of the five primary migration targets.  It's well within the capability of moderators to handle through flags.