# Flagging Move to Another Site Not Listed

Tags: feature-request, flags, stack-exchange

Many times I see questions on Stackoverflow that clearly belong on other sites, especially the [Android Stackexchange](http://android.stackexchange.com).  Because of this I usually add the comment

> This belongs on [site name and link], you should ask there for a proper response.

or something similar to this.  If I am able to I flag the post and press the appropriate site in the image below.

[image: Flagging]

**This is the appropriate thing to do, I was wondering why there are only 5 sites on there, why not a search box to look for ALL of the available sites on stackexchange/stackoverflow?**

Comment: In all actuality I'm curious what question you believe belongs on Android.SE that you've found.

Comment: @Makoto I actually don't remember the question.  There are various ones.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate; this is asking the reason why whereas the duplicate requested is asking for more options carte blanche.

Comment: As well as suggesting a search for all sites.

Comment: @Makoto given your concern, is [Why does Close | Off-Topic | Other SE site not list all sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278497/why-does-close-off-topic-other-se-site-not-list-all-sites?lq=1) a better duplicate?  Frankly the question is asked enough, that a little research by the OP should find any one of the duplicates on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't migration targets for *all* sites available.

If you do feel that a particular question belongs on another site, flag it for moderator attention.  But *before you do*, be sure that the question is not only on-topic for that site, but is well-written and suitable to get an answer.

Comment: ... and off-topic here!!