# Why was I asked to not use the mod attention flag for migration?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, declined-flags, migration

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505146/how-to-convert-cartesian-to-spherical-coordinates-for-hotspots-on-a-360-image) was recently asked on Stack Overflow.

I thought the question itself looked fine and could not find it to be a duplicate, however the question specifically asks for a mathematical solution to his problem:

> I need the Math for converting these cartesian coordinates to a spherical from the centre of the sphere

Nowhere in the question does the OP request a specific programming language either, and only stated that it is to be used in Unity. Which has support for C#, UnityScript (A JS variant), and other C languages through dll's.

I felt like this question was good enough to not flag it for deletion, so I went to the flag asking for migration. As I thought it would be a better fit for the [maths exchange site](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but since this is not one of the default option I did some research on how to handle migration requests for other SE sites.

Here I found [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/448842) (community post that has seen edits by mods) which places down some guidelines as of when to flag for migration. In my opinion it followed these guidelines, and so the answer states:

> If you think so, you can flag the question for moderator attention and request that they migrate it for you.

which also shows in the flow diagrams.

And [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295161/8628766) also saying you can flag it for moderator attention.

So I raised the following custom flag:

> Question is off-topic for StackOverflow as it just requests for a mathematical function (quote: "I need the math for converting"). there is no programming language specified either that the answer should be in. Think this should rather belong on math.exhange

which got rejected with the message "declined - please use the standard close reasons to close questions, rather than the 'requires moderator attention' flags".

The message struck me as slightly odd as I didn't request it to be closed (so wouldn't vote for it to be closed) but rather migrated.

Note that I raised this flag *before* there was an accepted answer on it (which is there now, and which is a purely mathematical answer). Else it wouldn't be viable for migration already anyway.

Was I wrong to use a moderator attention flag for this despite accepted resources pointing towards "acceptance" of custom flags for this? How should I have handled this?

Comment: Why didn't you just vote for close using the off topic and migration option? Were you just unaware that it existed?

Comment: Because i could only vote to migrate to meta, superuser, tex.se, dba.se, or stats.se using the default flag, neither of which suits the topic either @JeremyP

Comment: It gives you the option of "other stack exchange site" which you could probably specify in the comments. Or you could have added a comment to the question asking which language they were using.

Comment: I just read the migration guide and you are right it says you can flag for moderator attention if the migration site is not on the "approved list" but I still think it would have been more constructive for you to ask the questioner to add a language.

Comment: Apparantly i cannot see the "other" option until 3k rep. Thanks for your guidance

Comment: Personally, I'd not want to migrate that post. It is not nearly high-quality enough to fit on Math.SE. We try to avoid migrating bad questions, and this is just a 'gimme-the-math' post, the Math.SE equivalent of gimme-the-codez posts on SO. That the post is off-topic *here* and roughly fits the topic *there* is not enough reason to migrate, see [What is migration and how does it work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250)

Comment: Expanding on what Martijn said, there is an *extremely* high bar for migration. Questions need to be (A) unquestionably off-topic on the site where they are asked, (B) unquestionably on-topic on the site where they're to be migrated, and (C) high enough quality that it doesn't seem as if we're dumping our unwanted trash on another community. So, while you're free to request migration via moderator flags, prepare for some of those flags to be declined because it is such a high bar. Increase your odds by paying lip service to these criteria in your flag message, explaining how they're met.

Comment: @remy_rm I have 4k rep and [I don't see an "other" option](https://i.imgur.com/OMoMrt8.png)

Comment: @VLAZ - I don't think is an "other *site*" option. But there is an option to give a custom "off topic because..." reason.

Comment: @JohnY Ah, OK. I thought OP was talking about "other" as an option to the migration destinations, not a different thing. My bad.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm the mod who declined your flag. [Martijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) [sums up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379861/why-was-i-asked-to-not-use-the-mod-attention-flag-for-migration#comment667988_379861) the reasoning for the declined flag.

> Personally, I'd not want to migrate that post. It is not nearly high-quality enough to fit on Math.SE. We try to avoid migrating bad questions, and this is just a 'gimme-the-math' post, the Math.SE equivalent of gimme-the-codez posts on SO. That the post is off-topic here and roughly fits the topic there is not enough reason to migrate, see [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work/10250#10250) – Martijn Pieters♦ 1 hour ago

### Common migration flagging mistakes

There's a few issues with migration I regularly come across.

- Flagging to migrate posts that are not on topic for the target site. ([don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=&q=%5Bmigration%5D%20crap))
- Flagging to migrate posts that are also on topic for this site.
- Flagging to migrate a post that is too old to migrate.

### Behind the scenes

It's also worth mentioning, the Stack Overflow mods are often not experts on the target domain when requesting migrations. If the flagger is a high rep user on the target site, it's usually safe to migrate the question. If not and the question looks like it might be a fit for the target site, it involves talking to people on the target site and asking if they want us to migrate the question. If there's any doubt on that point, I decline the flag. Otherwise I'm wasting mod time for the target site also.

### What to do instead

So unless you have clear domain knowledge of the target site, it's wise not to flag for migration. Instead use one of the standard close reasons, that will bump a post into the review queues. This way the community can handle question closure, without the need for moderator attention. Custom mod flags should only be used when the standard site processes won't suffice.

Comment: 100% agreed with your decline and logic, but I think a tweak to your decline reason could have provided the same enlightenment earlier. When I decline these migration requests, I basically say something along the lines of what Martijn did: it's not high enough quality to migrate, you should just vote to close it instead. That way, you're addressing the flagger's confusion head-on (that is, the standard site processes don't give them any way to migrate to Math.SE), instead of appearing to tell them to do the impossible.

Comment: @CodyGray interestingly I updated my gist of decline reasons, the other day, to include quite a few migration decline reasons to cover the above scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for expanding @CodyGray . It is as you say, I trust a mods decision to decline a flag, but was mostly confused by the message (as per the title).  Though it has been made clear now.

Answer (score 7):

Your custom flag is a bit ambiguous. It reads like the standard off-topic: general computing flag:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

That's different from a migration flag. Migration flags should generally clearly state the following:

1. You want the question migrated to a target site (instead of *it may belong on a target site*)
2. The question is on-topic there (referring to the help center of the target site why that's the case)
3. The question is off-topic here (referring to the help center of this site why that's the case)

You only stated the question was off-topic here, which is nearly equivalent to the *Close* -> *Off-topic* -> *Other* close reason. Since there's an equivalent close reason to what you stated in the custom flag, the mod reviewing it declined the flag.

<sub>Since you have less than 3K rep, you unfortunately can't use the *Other* close reason. You might want to use the *Blatantly off-topic* flag instead</sub>

Comment: I see. According to those guidelines it indeed wasn't clear/specific enough. I indeed cannot see the "other" close reason, which i would've probably gone for had I had the option to. I'll keep in mind using the *blatantly off-topic* flag instead in combination with a comment. Thanks for the information!

Comment: You should be showing that the question is not only on topic on the target site, but a *high quality* question on the target site.  An on topic, but low quality, question is not a good migration candidate.

Comment: @Servy My answer was trying to address the title, why the OP was asked to use a different flag. Of course, for migration, the question should also be high quality, but stating that in the flag to the moderator doesn't really help imo, since it's a subjective assessment. Luckily, Yvette's answer covers that part.