# Why does Stack Overflow closed off-topic no longer list suggested SE site that is on-topic?

Tags: discussion, bug

For the better part of the past 5-years, when a question on Stack Overflow was closed as off-topic due to a question pertaining to general computing hardware or software, the first (most chosen) reason suggested Super User as the proper site. That would be contained in the close message displayed at the top of the question after it was closed. I noticed yesterday that is no longer the case:

[image]

There was an older question from 2014 that related to the issue which I suspect was what prompted the addition of the suggested Stack Exchange site be placed in the closing message: [Why does Close | Off-Topic | Other SE site not list all sites?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278497/why-does-close-off-topic-other-se-site-not-list-all-sites)

Looking at the close message as it stands now, provides no direction to the user on where they should go to get their question answered. A manual comment was needed:

[image]

The close message displayed does list the link to the page that describes what is off-topic, but that falls short and would still leave the user wondering what SE site is the right site for the question.

The question at issue<sup>[1.]</sup> was Off-Topic, so it was correctly closed, but why isn't the reference to where to go listed in the close message?

*Footnotes:*

(1.) [Debian 9. Software raid(mdadm) problem with high cpu usage after disk change (closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59962556/debian-9-software-raidmdadm-problem-with-high-cpu-usage-after-disk-change)

Comment: Related feature request that seems to have been implemented with this change: [Remove the mention of “Super User” from the standard off-topic close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277872/7795130)

Comment: You wonder why more people do give of their time in a constructive way and try to help with this site. With good intent to ensure a new user that posts to the wrong site is constructively steered to the proper StackExchange site, the suggestion is met with anonymous downvotes? Even a dog knows the difference between being tripped over and being kicked. This culture needs to change.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin please publish here your email address so that all questions posted to inappropriate sites can be forwarded to you.  You can then help by reading the question and matching up the requirement with an SE site where it is on-topic by careful checking kf the rules and policies of the sites.

Comment: @MartinJames - How does that help better the interface new users see after posting to the wrong site? I'm here to help and happy to do it. Sites like this that rely on the willingness of others to contribute content and help make things better are ill-served by casting snide comments in their direction. The problem at hand is the removal of helpful information from the close banner. Charles Merriam had a very legitimate idea. But instead of a civil discussion regardin what he proposed, what transpired was a juvenile downvote party. Successful companies value all constructive input.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin picking the right site for a question is a non-trivial exercise that only one user has the responsibility and the full set of knowledge to achieve - the OP.  If you suggest other site/s that might be more suitable to a user who has already posted inappropriately,  the result is likely to be another inappropriate site getting an unwanted question, only this time, it will be your fault, (in the eyes of the OP and, possibly, the mods of the new site).  It is not the work of 'someone else' to pick the correct site!

Answer (score -21):

This new message is uselessly hostile.   How about:

---

Your question appears to be in the wrong place.  Stack Overflow is about programming questions and avoids questions about general hardware or software.  You can:

- [Edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/question/edit) so it is [on-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- Ask on a better-suited Stack Exchange site.  We have [many sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) for questions.   The three most likely sites for questions moving from Stack Overflow are:

  - [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) for hardware, software, and personal networking
  - [Server Fault](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) for managing, deploying, and installing IT systems in a business environment
  - [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for peer review of working code

It's probably a great question and thank you for writing it!

Comment: Exactly! If the selection in the Close dialog used to close the question lists the site that is relevant to the question (SuperUser is the 1st and most used reason)-- then at a minimum that site should be suggested in the close message ultimately displayed to the user.

Comment: Could you explain how you are characterizing this message as hostile? It states the rule then invites the user to improve it and stay, rather than shuffling them off to another site where they might run into the same problem. Hostile means unfriendly or antagonistic, which this message is neither.

Comment: "We don't allow"  "is not".  Feel free to use any metric you learning in advanced marketing or psychology or business communication.  Yes, the message is hostile because it prefers negative word choice, offers no customer validation, and provides closed end effective actions.

Comment: Meh.  Everyone's offended by something.

Comment: did you ask at metas of the sites you mention [whether they want to be referred this way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975/839601)?

Comment: I believe part of the intent with these new messages was to shorten them, not lengthen... Perhaps just a pointer to the Meta SE FAQ entry [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/194720)

Comment: @gnat  I did not, but I did link to their guidelines instead of the site directly and I did try to describe their purpose in one line.  For example, Code Review's line includes "working code" which appears to be the major peeve of poor referrals.

Comment: @HereticMonkey A link to an explanation would be better than no link and it may be worth rethinking if a shorter message or more information is better.   A link would provide more concise information if it were purpose-written rather than SE question.

Comment: I am offended by all suggestions that 'someone else', (and this is always site curators), do extra volunteer effort to do work that should have been done by OP's, whether 'new user', (and that term is used frequently when, in fact, all that can be demonstrated is 'new account'), or long-term vet.

Comment: I like this proposed message. It may be a bit longer but is also much clearer than the current one.

Comment: _"It's probably a great question and thank you for writing it!"_ This is demonstrably false in _most_ cases when questions are closed.

Comment: I think the exact wording here is a little overly positive given most questions that get closed as not "great questions".  Let's not lie to the user.  But the point has merit.  Just stating that the question is off-topic and to edit the question so it is on-topic is like a kick in the pants. You are effectively telling the user to go away so is not very friendly or welcoming. In needs to include some mechanism to point the user in a better direction. Linking to https://stackexchange.com/sites would be better. And even better if it went to https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic